# How to work with the Content Query Web Part (CQWP) & XSLT

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, content-query-web-part

I have been using SharePoint for a few years now, but limit of my skills include anything I can do in the browser and some stuff using Designer (Branding, Workflows).

I know how to use the CQWP to query SharePoint for content. I don't know how to write my own styles to output the content using XSLT.

Could someone recommend a great resource to help me get started using XSLT and the CQWP?

Comment: I'd be cautious about setting out to learn this now. If you're in 2013, learn how to use the search parts and display templates instead. If you're in 2010, just be aware that the design view in SharePoint designer goes away in 2013, making the maintenance of these sorts of things to be a bit more challenging.

Comment: The search parts and display templates are great and pretty easy to use. But remember that they use the search technology so items won't show up in a CSWP immediately they must be crawled first. For many uses that is fine, but is something to be aware of. Whereas the query parts will query the site and find the current content each time.

Comment: Thanks for the great information guys ... Unfortunately we are stuck on 2010 for the next 12-18 months and this is something I really need to learn how to use now. Do you guys know anywhere where I can learn how to do this?

Comment: Here is great blog to start editing CQWP using XSLT. check [Link](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/01/21/displaying-results-in-multiple-columns-using-the-content-query-web-part/)